# Simplest way of doing an OAuth 1.0 request in PHP?

Tags: php, oauth

I'm writing some example PHP code for how to use [an API](http://remote.bergcloud.com/developers/littleprinter/reference/push) that requires an OAuth 1.0 authenticated POST request.

I have the consumer key and secret, and also an access token and secret. These are specific to my app using the API, and I don't need users to do an OAuth dance to get a unique access token/secret.

Using python, I could do something like this:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key='myCONSUMERkey', secret='myCONSUMERsecret') 
token = oauth.Token(key='myACCESStoken', secret='myACCESSsecret')
client =  oauth.Client(consumer, token)

response, data = client.request(
                        'http://example.org/api/endpoint,
                        method='POST',
                        body='Hello World!',
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})
```

But I'm stumped as to how to do this using PHP. I've seen examples of a lot of PHP OAuth libraries but they're all 2- or 3-legged examples that don't match what I need to do (ie, using an existing access token and secret).

I'd rather not use the [PHP OAuth extension](https://www.php.net/oauth) as that seems complicated to install for some quick example code.

Comment: The example from the extension docs for doing a fetch doesnt seem much more complicated than your python example http://us3.php.net/manual/en/oauth.fetch.php

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear (I'll update question) - installing PECL extensions seems overly complicated for a piece of example code, only a small part of which is about OAuth. I was hoping for a library that could be downloaded and `require`d. But it's been a few years since I did a lot of PHP, and maybe installing PECL extensions is something all PHP developers know these days?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) with the [oauth plugin](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/plugins/oauth-plugin.html), look pretty simple and you can install it with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: Thanks, although using an entire framework just so I can use its OAuth plugin seems a bit over the top...

Comment: its an http client, which you are going to need anyway, doesnt seem much different to pulling in Oauth2 in python?

Comment: Ahh, my apologies - I didn't read it properly and thought it was a CodeIgniter-style framework. I'll take a better look.